# Create year calendar from list of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a list of dates like this:

```
Frequency   Date
Weekly  07/01/2015
Fortnightly 07/01/2015
Monthly 07/01/2015
Fortnightly 14/01/2015
Weekly  14/01/2015
Weekly  21/01/2015
.............

So on
```

I would like to put these on a cal like this

```
January 
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
```

with days a month going horizontally across the top 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
 and so on.

Is there quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using PIVOT function in SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use formulas such as;

IF(AND(MONTH(date)=month,DAY(date)=day on the top),true,false)

the formula commands are the onces in Capitals, and the smaller caps would be your data.